# Django 2.x: Is using the Primary Key of a Model in the URL pattern a security concern?

Tags: django, python-3.x, security, django-urls

The id (PK) of a model/ DB can be passed to and used in the URL pattern. Everyone, including hackers, would be able to piece together some information about my DB from this and the actual data in the template.

My questions are kind of general at this point. I would just like to understand how the info above could be used to compromise the data. Or if someone could point me to some further reading about this topic I would appreciate it.

This is a general question as I am trying to gain more understanding into securing Django sites. I have read several articles but nothing's satisfied the question.

Code:
Where the href passes the blogs id to be used in url matching and ultimately pulling data from the DB in the views/ template:

```html
<a href= "{% url 'details' blog.id %}">
```

and

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:blog_id>/', views.details, name = 'details'),
]
```

And the URL being: 
domain/appname/blog_id/

TL;DR: Can you hack my site with the few pieces of information I am freely giving away concerning the backend?

Comment: Since you mention its a general question, you may be interested to look at [What technical details should a programmer of a web application consider before making the site public?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before/46760#46760)

Answer (score 7):

First it depends on how your ids are generated. The default in Django is to use sequential numbers, which gives away the following (non-exhaustive) information:

- Someone can easily try other ids to see what they get. If you haven't properly protected access to ids you don't want to show, someone might be able to see content they shouldn't see. Many information leaks were just due to this: Guess the URL et voilà! Something that was supposed to be published tomorrow is suddenly leaked today. The same applies for dates in the URL. Of course, if you have proper checks for who's allowed to view "draft" posts, there's no harm.
- By trying all ids, you can find out numbers: maybe you don't want others to know how many products you have in your database because it's sensitive information. If I can just do `/products/4924` to fetch info about product #4924, I can easily create a script to quickly increase the number until I get 404 Not Found, by which time I know there are 10252 products in your database.
- If you have a form to make changes to an order and use the `id` in the URL to determine which order to change (never do just that by the way, make sure you check the order belongs to the user), someone could just pick different ids to mess up with other people's orders. That can happen easily with an `UpdateView` where you forget to check permissions.

Regarding the last one: I see plenty of posts here on SO where people show their `UpdateView` for changing user profiles and other really sensitive information. In most cases the `pk` is the URL parameter used to fetch the `UserProfile`. But I almost never see a decorator or mixin (`PermissionRequiredMixin` or `UserPassesTestMixin`) to check that the user is actually the one authorised to modify this object. I just pray it's left out for clarity sake :-)

On the other hand, in many case there's not much harm using ids. This site, StackOverflow uses a sequential id for the URL of a question/answer. Nothing serious can happen here if I randomly try other ids. And apparently they are happy to share how many questions and answers have been posted so far (57478609 when you posted this question).

**TL;DR**: Except giving the ability to visitors to "count" objects in your database, all other security issues with using sequential ids aren't real issues if you take care about your security. But by using random ids, e.g. uuids in your URLs (not necessarily replacing the `pk` in the db) you can reduce the risk if you forgot to secure something where people can guess ids (or your intern forgot and it got passed your code review and unit tests somehow).

Answer (score 3):

You asked a general question, and the general answer would be: "It depends"

> TL;DR: Can you hack my site with the few pieces of information I am freely giving away concerning the backend?

This question is broad. You could hack a site with a toothpick if you annoy the site owner by poking them with it until they give you the password.

Instead I'll assume you asked the titular question:

**Q: Are PKs in URLs a security concern?**

**A: They can be**.

In your example you mention blog posts- so lets assume your site has plenty of users all writing blog posts. Now you add the ability for a User to set their latest blog entry to "private". Blog posts marked private only show up on the dashboard for the user that wrote them, and don't show up on everyone else's blog feeds e.g:

```
{% for article in articles if not article.private %}
    ... <article feed stuff here>
{% endif %}
```

Great!

However, one of your users posts a private article and looks at the address bar which shows https://myblog.blog/articles/42 and then at a previous article they wrote yesterday which is https://myblog.blog/articles/37 and deduces that the ID's are sequential. On a whim they type into the address bar https://myblog.blog/articles/41 and oh dear, now they're looking at an article that someone else posted that for the sake of argument we'll say was also set to private.

Because we had no check in place to make sure that the user looking at the (private) blog post was permitted to do so we exposed someones private information. Which is bad enough for blog posts but a very expensive disaster for e.g. bank accounts (there are plenty of examples of major banks slipping up on this particular issue)

Django has a robust system for dealing with this sort of thing: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test

The argument can still be made that as well as permissions checks, good practice would be to use UUIDs (or short UUIDs) for the id "slugs" in the URLs of any objects that you would rather weren't guessable.

Also, not security related but on the subject of URLs for public articles and blog posts you may find this interesting: https://wellfire.co/learn/fast-and-beautiful-urls-with-django/

Comment: wrt/ "use UUIDs (or short UUIDs) for the PKs", it's better to keep the integer auto pk for internal use (joins etc) and use a distinct unique arbitrary value for urls.